# cannot resolve circular dependency issue

Tags: c#, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I have faced circular dependency issue while i am accessing classA method from ClassB.
I had following references earlier on my solution. 
classA method calls -> class B method , this is fine with referencing libraryB to library A.
But then i had a requirement of calling classA method from ClassB but then i cannt add reference because it is making circular dependency issue.

So i have tried to add an interface to resolve the issue.

Now i want to call  GetDataFromDB() method from class B .

How to crate _classAObj in Class B . Do i need to tranmet from the index class where the main method resides.

[image]

```
using ClassLibraryC;

namespace ClassLibraryB
{
    public class ClassB 
    {
        IClassA _classAObj = null;

        public ClassB()
        { }

        public ClassB(IClassA objc)
        {
            _classAObj = objc;
        }

        public string GetDataFromDB(string cdata)
        {
            // connect db and get data
            // using data reader
              while(rdr.read())
             {
                // need to call StartProcess() method of classA
                _classAObj.StartProcess("data");
             }
            return  "client data:name : xyz: age:23";
        }
    }
```

---

```
using ClassLibraryB;
using ClassLibraryC;

namespace ClassLibraryA
{
    public class ClassA : IClassA
    {

        public ClassA() {}

        public void  GetClientData()
        {
            ClassB b = new ClassB();
            string result=  b.GetDataFromDB("c1");
        }

        public void StartProcess(string d)
        {
            string data = d; 
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using ClassLibraryA;

namespace ClassLibraryC
{
   public interface IClassA
    {
        void StartProcess(string d);
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace Start
{
    class Index
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassA a = new ClassA();
            a.GetClientData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what your problem is. Your interface solution in Library C is the normal way to fix it, and you did that already. What is your actual question?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I need to call StartProcess() method of classA from  GetDataFromDB() method of classB. So do i need to transmit the classA object from GetClientData() method of ClassB using overloaded constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a instance of ClassA in to ClassB using `this`.

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public ClassA() {}

    public void  GetClientData()
    {
        ClassB b = new ClassB(this);
        string result=  b.GetDataFromDB("c1");
    }

    public void StartProcess(string d)
    {
        string data = d; 
    }
}
```

You can get rid of the `ClassB()` constructor, it is not needed anymore, you only need the `public ClassB(IClassA objc)` constructor.

Comment: Can you see any problem in GetDataFromDB() of classB. I am calling back classA method from there. Is this approach is best or i need to go for events.